# Помогите понять струкутру матрицы для transformation DirectX 11 C++

Tags: c++, математика, матрицы, 3d, directx-11

Представим что на текущей стадии у нас есть результат в виде хексагона:

[image: 2D Hexagon]

для того, чтобы совершить ротацию для данной фигуры, необходимо создать струкутуру данных Constant Buffer и непосредственно привязать это к пайплайну.
Объявление матрицы для transformation:

```
struct ConstantBuffer
{
    struct
    {
        float element[4][4];
    } transformation;
};
```

Затем создаётся объект данной структуры в виде:

```
const ConstantBuffer ConstBuff = 
{
    { std::cos(angle), std::sin(angle), 0.f, 0.f,
     -std::sin(angle), std::cos(angle), 0.f, 0.f,
     0.f,              0.f,             1.f, 0.f,
     0.f,              0.f,             0.f, 1.f,
            
    }
}
```

**angle** - это параметр который передаётся методу внутри которого и создаётся ConstBuffer и этот метод вызывается каждый фрейм с разными значениями angle.

Каким образом работает трансформация фигуры в данном случае и зачем на первые два элемента первого и второго ряда матрицы идёт применение cos и sin функций для angle, при этом одна из них "отрицается" (negate) используя '-'.

Comment: Лекции по линейной алгебре и аналитической геометрии

Comment: Мы в вузе до этого полгода лекций шли. За один ответ не описать.

Comment: Вот тут наглядное и отличное объяснение ответа на мой вопрос https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cN97hkDrzcc&list=PLqCJpWy5Fohe8ucwhksiv9hTF5sfid8lA&index=4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтоб понять откуда берутся `sin`, `cos`, `+` и `-` в коэффициентах левого верхнего угла матрицы стоит для начала рассмотреть плоский случай.

Возьмём декартову плоскость, и нарисуем на ней единичный квадрат с координатами вершин в точках `(0,0)`, `(1,0)`, `(0,1)` и `(1,1)`.

Теперь повернём этот квадрат вокруг точки `(0,0)` на угол `a` (положительное значение a соответствует вращению против часовой стрелки).

Из школьного курса геометрии мы знаем, что:

Точка `(1,0)` переместится в координаты `(cos(a),sin(a))` — это, собственно, определение синуса и косинуса.

Для малых углов `a` (< 90 градусов) очевидно, что точка `(0,1)` сдвинется влево (в сторону отрицательных значений, в минус), настолько же, насколько точка `(1,0)` поднялась вверх. Её координаты станут `(-sin(a),cos(a))`. Для больших значений `a` эта формула также верна, но будет не так очевидно откуда минус.

Точка `(1,1)` переместится в координаты `(cos(a)-sin(a), sin(a)+cos(a))`, это просто сумма координат новых положений точек `(1,0)` и `(0,1)`.

Можно продолжит изыскания с любыми размерами квадрата, сделав его прямоугольником со сторонами `x` и `y`, и заметить, что точка с координатами `(x,y)` при повороте на угол `a` вокруг начала координат оказывается в координатах `(x*cos(a) + y*(-sin(a)), x*sin(a) + y*cos(a))`.

А получение вектора с координатами `(x*a11 + y*a12, x*a21 + y*a22)` из вектора `(x, y)` — это результат умножения вектора `(x, y)` на матрицу

```
a11, a21
a12, a22
```

Смотрим чему равны коэффициенты в формуле поворота, и получаем матрицу линейного преобразования:

```
 cos(a), sin(a)
-sin(a), cos(a)
```

Comment: Благодарю вас за уделённое время. Ваш ответ был очень полезен!